# Java Socket connected but can't sent message by OutputStream.write() but PrintStream will work

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io

I'm an amateur in java socket programming. As I say in title, When I using `PrintStream` for socket output,it works;but it doesn't work if I using simply `OutputStream`.
I know the the client connected to the server cause' the server got the info of the client.So I think there must be something wrong with I/O stream, not the socket connection.

btw, I even use the `flush()` method for `OutputStream`.I think `flush()` will force to send all bytes, but it seems like it didn't work.

The Client Code:**@line 12**:

```java
public class Clinet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println("==========Client============");
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 8888);// Server's addr and port
        socket.setSoTimeout(3000);

        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

        String msgToSent = "Hello TCP";
        outputStream.write(msgToSent.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();// FIXME:why flush() didn't work?why msg wasn't sent.

        // read from socket input
        String receivedMsg = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes());
        System.out.println(receivedMsg);

        socket.close();
    }

}
```

When I using a filter stream like `PrintStream`,the `msg` can be sent to server.

The Server Code: if using `PrintStream` it will work perfectly with the Client:

```java
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);

        while (true) {
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new ServerHandler(client)).start();
        }
    }
}

class ServerHandler implements Runnable {
    private Socket client;

    ServerHandler(Socket client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress clientAddr = client.getInetAddress();
            int clientPort = client.getPort();
            System.out.println("client connected @ " + clientAddr + ":" + clientPort);

            InputStream inputStream = client.getInputStream();
            OutputStream outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

            while (true) {
                String msg = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes());// FIXME: Why Server didn't receive Client's msg?
                System.out.print("/" + clientAddr + "@" + clientPort + " : ");
                System.out.println(msg);

                String reply = "I received " + msg.length() + " words.";// return how many words the server got.
                outputStream.write(reply.getBytes());
                outputStream.flush();// flush to ensure send all msg,but seems doesn't work
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why it "works" with `PrintStream` but you obviously have to close the socket before `readAllBytes()` will return, so this can't work as-is.  Close the output stream on the client before trying to read the server's response.

Comment: oh,you're right.It won't work even if I using PrintStream.The problem is from InputStream not OutputStream.But why you need closed socket first? And Why it works (I've tested) when I use the BufferedReader and PrintStream for both server and client?

Comment: When you use `BufferedReader` how?

Comment: @user207421 When I read from socketinputstream. like in client:`String receivedMsg = new String(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).readLine());` Also use printstream for the socketoutputstream.

Comment: Right, so `readLine()` only reads one line, not the entire stream. Just as it says in the Javadoc.